# Capture the index value of a cell but only from the visible cells on the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsindexpath

I am trying to trigger some code based on if the cell I selected becomes the first or last cell on the users screen. I'm not trying to capture the index value of the data array. Just the index value of the cell that is visible on the screen. I'm sure this to create an array of visible cells.

> NSArray *indexPathsForVisibleRows = [myTableView
>   indexPathsForVisibleRows];

But I keep hitting a dead end trying to then capture an index value based on that array.
I tried to use a CGPoint and convert that, but I keep getting an error. Any insight would be most helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation for the return value of that method:

> An array of NSIndexPath objects each representing a row
>   index and section index that together identify a visible row in the
>   table view. Returns nil if no rows are visible.

The array returned from that method contains `NSIndexPaths`.

```
NSArray *indexPathsForVisibleRows = [myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

for(NSIndexPath *eachIndexPath in indexPathsForVisibleRows)
{
   NSInteger row = eachIndexPath.row;
   NSInteger section = eachIndexPath.section;

   UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:eachIndexPath];
   if(cell.isSelected)
   {
      // this is our selected cell
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm not following how to figure out the index value of the selected cell from the visible rows?

Comment: Thanks Dima,
Could you also put your other answer up there as well, as I think it's helpful to see that as well. Then I'll up-vote your answer.